# Stop onEmailVerificationLink from opening another tab

Tags: javascript, meteor

My meteor codes works fine but I find that every time I click on the link in emails sent from meteor, the browser opens a new tab, sometimes I end up with many tabs open which is not good.
The links are results of sendPasswordResetEmail or sendVerificationEmail.
Is there a way to only use only one browser tab and not have so many open to the same app? Thanks